# Override skip.phtml results on langage switcher disappear

Tags: magento2, layout, template

I'm trying to override template skip.phtml file (in the top of Magento) with this layout default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
            <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
                <block class="Vendor\PhoneStore\Block\PhoneStore" name="skip_to_content" template="Vendor_PhoneStore::html/skip.phtml" />
             </container>
        </container> 
    </referenceContainer>     
</page>
```

The override works but the langage switcher was disappeared

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by this layout override

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Wetag\PhoneStore\Block\PhoneStore" name="skip_to_content" template="Wetag_PhoneStore::html/skip.phtml" before="-" />
    </referenceContainer>     
</page>
```